# How to specify home directory with 'adduser' when user creation fails on a machine with NFS home directory and Kerberos authentication

Tags: cloud, nfs, chown, adduser, kerberos

I am using `adduser --disabled-password` to create a user that uses Kerberos authentication for letting them sign into their account. Therefore, the password is predefined by a central Kerberos database.

Furthermore, the `/home` directory on the machine is symlinked to a directory on an `NFS` storage. So, using `adduser --disabled-password newusername` ends up in an error that I'm led to believe is caused by the NFS filesystem:

```
Stopped: chown 1002:1003 /home/newusername: Invalid argument
Removing directory `/home/newusername' ...
Removing user `newusername' ...
Removing group `newusername' ...
groupdel: group 'newusername' does not exist
adduser: `groupdel newusername' returned error code 6. Exiting.
```

I tried `adduser --disabled-password --no-create-home newusername`. The user was then created and they could easily sign into the machine with their Kerberos authentication. Their home directory was however not created. I created it for them on the NFS, but then they could not create any folders there. Then I deleted their home directory and tried giving them `sudo` access to create their own home directory. They did it but then they could not create any folders inside their own home directory without `sudo`.

Is there a way to specify `home` directory for this particular user when using `adduser --disabled-password` so that I can create their home directory in the root of the machine and then move it onto the NFS? Or is there a better way of doing this?

I already have three other users on this same machine that were all created upon the creation of the machine and before migrating the `/home` directory to the NFS from the cloud storage.

Comment: Which NFS implementation is it? Perhaps it does not allow setting ownership to non-existent UIDs/GIDs. Or maybe it has root_squash enabled, so `chown` is not allowed.

Comment: Implementation is NFSv4

Comment: That's the standard, not the implementation. Is it Linux NFS, some custom thing by a NAS box, Solaris' NFS...?

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot to change the ownership of the home directory to the user after you created it. You would do that using the `chown` command.

Consider using [pam_mkhomedir](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_mkhomedir) for having this done automatically.

Also, consider configuring your system such that it will import user IDs from your server. If there's a kerberos system, I would guess there is also some kind of LDAP server that offers account information via network. Then you would not have to configure each account individually.

Comment: I did use the `chown` command afterwards, but the result was still the same. Unfortunately, `pam_mkhomedir` also does not work.. The user gets the same message ('cannot chdir to home directory') and I cannot change any of the permissions for them.